# CodeNarc Maven Plugin

Tags: groovy, codenarc

We have a project that uses Groovy extensively and we use Maven to build our artifacts. (IntelliJ as our IDE)

We wanted to incorporate some automated code-style checking, and thought we might use **codecarc-maven-plugin**. However, since that was from Codehaus, which gone now, is the plugin actively supported somewhere else?

Any other good options to run a Groovy style checker automatically during a Maven build?

Answer (score 1):

That's a good catch. I'll add a pull request to update the website link. You can find the new plugin information on GitHub: https://github.com/gleclaire/codenarc-maven-plugin